# Sharepoint branding tools

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, publishing-site, branding, design-manager

i am getting started with SharePoint branding. Google search show me two major type of customization :

1. master page customization
2. composed look customization

Could you guys tell me if there are more ways and the tools i can used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey there I see you've tagged this question with "sharepoint-online". Are you sure customizing the MasterPage is an investment you want to make? Publishing sites as we knew it are pretty much obsolete when communication sites are rolled out. When you're still on-premises it makes a bit more sense.

That said, if you want to have a custom MasterPage you can start here: [Master Pages in SharePoint Add-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/master-pages-sharepoint-add-in)

Another good read on branding SharePoint is [Branding SharePoint sites in the SharePoint Add-in model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/branding-sharepoint-sites-sharepoint-add-in)

Also don't forget Microsofts own source for development on the Office 365 platform [dev.office.com](https://dev.office.com) and [dev.office.com/patterns-and-practices](https://dev.office.com/patterns-and-practices)

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I am pretty much a beginner,if you know an alternative to master page customization,let me know please.

Comment: Hey Keshav a great way to start is using a custom CSS file and link that using the ALternate CSS property. https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Branding.AlternateCSSAndSiteLogo 

If you're looking for a Responsive UI then the PnP solution is a good starting point: https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Tools/tree/master/Solutions/SharePoint.UI.Responsive

Answer (score 3):

When I started with branding, followed these steps and found these blogs to be invaluable:

**Step 1**: - Design a good master page, i.e. an HTML page which will be converted to master page, follow this [blog](http://blog.navantis.com/creating-a-new-master-page-in-sharepoint-2013/).

Step 2: - Follow this [blog](http://blog.navantis.com/create-a-custom-page-layout-in-sharepoint-2013/) for example on layouts which you will have to create for a master page:

I hope that will prove to be helpful for you as well.

Answer (score 2):

my references are

[changecase blog](http://changecase.net/blog/2015/10/28/safely-customize-master-pages-in-sharepoint-2013/)

[sharepointexperience blog](http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2015/10/part-2-implement-custom-css-in-sharepoint-master-pages/)

which gave me useful info. And do yourself a favour and try to do it WITHOUT SharePoint-Designer because "SPD" is crap and buggy :-/

Comment: Most of the blog post use spd and other methods are not really documented for  a beginner . Can you elaborate please what are the best steps i should follow?

Answer (score 1):

actually,  it starts with HTML page, by adding your custom CSS and JS, and One main component among all is adding WebpartZone (use snippet for it)  within your page.

This is a [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430141.aspx#bk_intro) for SP2010, but I hope this link will provide you the needed information

Comment: thanks it really help me understand the different part of sharepoint page.But still for a complete beginner i feel there is some steps that are skipped

Comment: Ok, So start with this sample [HTML master page](http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/releases/view/97062)  , you need to [convert](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/how-to-convert-an-html-file-into-a-master-page-in-sharepoint)  it to SharePoint Master Page and then apply as default master page for the particular site.  (it all will be done by SharePoint Designer)

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. It wasn't that hard to implement,the hardest part was to actually find resources(tutorials for beginners).But now i was told in the comments to not use design manager??? @cjs

Comment: I would suggest to start branding you site, you will get to know pro &cons of each development approach/tool ;)